# Compressor detection issue when running curl command from bash script in Docker container

Tags: linux, bash, script, curl, docker

I want to execute `curl` using bash script inside the Docker container.

This is my script file `script.sh` that I added to the container:

`curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/tests/test -d usr/share/elasticsearch/data/test.json`

The content of json file is the following (the idea to add `\` comes from [this thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-a-new-document/35281/9)):

```
"{\"id\":\"978-1-60741-503-9\",\"doi\":\"\"}"
```

When I enter into the running Docker container and do `bash myscript.sh`, the result is:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed
>   to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to
>   parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor
>   detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed
>   xcontent bytes"}}

However, if I change the script to this one:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/tests/test -d "{\"id\":\"978-1-60741-503-9\",\"doi\":\"\"}"
```

then it works without errors.

So, why doesn't it like the json file???

UPDATE:

When I add `@` behind `usr/` as suggested in comments, I get the following error:

> Warning: Couldn't read data from file  Warning:
>   "usr/share/elasticsearch/data/test.json", this makes an empty 
>   Warning: POST.   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time
>   Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100   201  100   201    0     0    740      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
>   --:--:--   738 {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed
>   to parse, document is
>   empty"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse,
>   document is empty"},"status":400}

The file `test.json`:

```
"{\"id\":\"123\",\"field\":\"456\"}"
```

Comment: Try this `-d @usr/share/elasticsearch/data/test.json`. Note the use of `@`

Answer (score 1):

The `json` file passed as argument to `curl -d` should be preceded by `@` symbol.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/tests/test -d @usr/share/elasticsearch/data/test.json
```